Why is there a "just" in this sentence? | I did message her back and just say is this normal
On TV, a woman is talking about how she bought a medicine online from someone and was rushed to the hospital. She says:

"I did message her back and just say is this normal?"
ITV - I almost died (see:4:47-4:52)

I wonder why she used "just" in the second sentence. I said the sentence to myself a few times, and it meant the same -to me- without "just". But maybe there is a reason for its presence in the sentence, like implying suprise, worry, fear, uncertainty, etc, which probably native English speakers would feel or anticipate.
Does it really imply anything of that sort?

I think this morning chat show has some great examples of natural English, English spoken by everyday people. The vocabulary you hear is just, in a word, great. I applaud you.

To the close voter: This is not a proofreading request, it's asking about meaning and usage. To the OP: Look up the different meanings of "just", you'll probably find what you asking for.

I already looked up but more than one function seems to apply to it and I can't decide which one.

just adverb (ONLY) B1 only; simply (Cambridge Dictionary).

"Just" is a common filler word. Like "actually", "you know", "kind of", "like", etc. It does have a meaning, but often it doesn't need to be there. People say these words to fill time, often because they are thinking of what to say next.
I've noticed that you submit a lot of questions about transcripts of speech from 'live' television broadcasts such as the news. These are often members of the public being interviewed about newsworthy events. They are not professional broadcasters, they are probably nervous of the cameras and trying to recall what they've seen as they describe it. It may be good English practice to watch these and try to understand them because receiving extemporaneous speech is an important part of being fluent in a language, but it isn't worth scrutinising the grammar because it isn't planned.

@Mari-Lou A, I am not after grammer. I am asking if there is a reason for using it when there is no need to use it, because sometimes we use some words just because it doesn't change the meaning but adds a feeling to it. sometimes it emphasizes person being unsure, sometimes fearful, sometimes excited etc. So I am asking about whether it implies such an additional feeling to the sentence.

@Mari-LouA I believe you've summarised my answer - it's not wrong, and it is useful for learners to hear. I don't think it's appropriate for you to tell other users how to vote. The system of voting exists so that decisions to close have the weight of more than one user behind them.

@Astralbee, The reason I am asking it is I want to learn the feeling and thinking in the mind of speaker of english, not just what I hear. even if it is a filler word, there is usually a reason for using that particular one out of so many. I don't think speakers are choosing filler words randomly such as I will choose this filler word today. And when I research, I see that you just can't use filler words in place of one another randomly. For instance if "just" is a filler word in the above sentence, can you replace it with other filler words you listed such as "you know", "kind of".?

@Mari-LouA, I understand, no problem. Thanks for your explanation.

@Mari-LouA But why are you arguing for it being on-topic in a comment on my answer? Argue with someone who says its off-topic.

I did argue in the comment section below the question. Anyway, thanks. The close vote has been removed. I must have convinced someone else! I have deleted my two previous comments.

I think she means "I merely asked her if this [symptom} was normal" as distinct from, perhaps, panicking and claiming that something was seriously wrong.

As a filler word, "just" can carry the implication "my actions are reasonable, this isn't excessive, I could have been more extreme and it would have been justified but I didn't." A speaker might subconsciously sprinkle that filler word into their speech in order to seem as moderate as possible. There are also some people who favor a particular filler word purely out of habit.

@HitenStyle, Thanks, good analysis. I understand better now. Yes, dictionary wise, it means "only/merely", and yes people think it is a "filler word" but above all it emphasizes reasonable aspect of the verb it accompanies. It is not randomly chosen to fill the speech. She really used "just" in her description of her talk on the phone to emphasize that she asked the question not in an angry, panicked, arguing tone of voice but rather a reasonable, logical, smooth conversation, which was the opposite of what was expected in such situations. So she said "I JUST asked..." instead of "I asked ..."

Astralbee's answer is the best thing to say about this quote and I'm glad it's the accepted answer. I'll contribute one too just to expand on why this particular filler word was used instead of another.
Filler words bring very little meaning to the sentence. You were right; if you repeat the sentence without "just," it means pretty much the same thing. And often filler words are used unconsciously, literally to fill time, because the speaker has not yet thought of the next word and doesn't want to either be silent* or say "Uhhhhhhhhh." I've been in religious contexts in which someone is called on to improvise spoken prayer, and over time they develop curious spoken habits, almost "tics," of inserting "just" very frequently: "Father God, I just want to say, Father God, that we just want to come before you and just worship you and just share, just, our hearts with you" etc.**
But sometimes "filler words" like this can have a small impact on the sentence. "Like" is often attacked as a filler word, in "Valley-girl"-style speech, and it can be inserted meaninglessly, but it also can be used in a way that affects the overall tone. If I say "Frankenstein is a seminal work of early science fiction," it is a very direct claim, using at least one word that isn't common in casual conversation. Someone making this point in an oral presentation might say "Frankenstein is a, like, seminal work of early, like, science fiction." The "likes" soften the directness of the sentence, and dilute the academic tone of the words and phrases that they precede. They distance the speaker from their choice of words somewhat, which can be valuable when you want to make strong or academic points but it's socially problematic to be strongly academic.
Similarly, "just" can sometimes bring in faint meanings of minimization. If we're to replace it with another word, "merely" can often work. "I just thought I'd look in and see how you're doing": Compared to "I'm here to see how you're doing," "just," along with the convoluted "thought I would," softens the intrusion of privacy and assures the hearer that it's "not a big deal." Similarly, in the original quote, adding "just" to "I said 'is this normal,'" suggests that this inquiry is not a big effort, or is not of great importance.

* Though coaches in public speaking will tell you that simply being silent while thinking of your next word is a better and more powerful choice than watering down your speech with words that don't have impact.
** Though this practice seems to go against the scriptural advice "When you pray, do not heap up empty phrases."

+1 for "minimization... merely"

To expand on the comment by @MichaelHarvey citing the definition "simply", the phrase "I did just say 'Is this normal'?"  means "I  merely asked a basic question, whether my symptoms were normal". The person is saying that she only wanted a bit of reassurance. She didn't have a probing conversation with the seller.
